# How can I find out when an Redux action is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm googling and I haven't really found anything, or I just don't understand it.  I have Redux Thunk and I'm going through their examples but I'm not sure if that will help me?

I normally would use a Promise.. but from what I understand when Redux updates the state, it is done Asyncronously.. so I don't think that would work?

```
export function setComposition( composition ) {  
  return { type: types.SET_COMPOSITION, composition };
}

export function doStuff() {
  // What I'd like to do:
  dispatch(setComposition).then(() => {
    console.log('done');
  });
}
```

EDIT:

This is what I was thinking of doing... but i dont think will work because doesn't the state get updated asynchronously?

```
export function setComposition( composition ) {  
  return Promise.resolve(
    return { type: types.SET_COMPOSITION, composition };
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add one more action to check if async action is done:

```
export function setComposition( composition ) {  
  return { type: types.SET_COMPOSITION, composition };
}
export function successComposition() {  
  return { type: types.SET_COMPOSITION_SUCCESS };
}

export function doStuff() {
    // What I'd like to do:
    dispatch(setComposition());
    yourAsyncFunction.then(() => {
    console.log('done');
    dispatch(successComposition());
  });
}
```

Comment: when you do dispatch(setComposition)... isn't that asynchronous?  (i'm using thunk).  so wouldn't the console.log('done') potentially be called before the composition is set in the global state?  unless i'm understanding all this incorrectly..

Comment: Redux-thunk allows to dispatch async functions, but your setComposition action is not async in this case you have async doStuff action with two plain actions for begin and for finish.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! A Redux Thunk is used in order to ensure that an asynchronous action, such as making a request to a database via axios, will indeed be processed asynchronously.

As such, unless your setComposition action needs to be async, you should not need to use a thunk. In the case that it is synchronous you could just do this to see when it is done:

```
dispatch(setComposition( compositionToSet )) //remember to pass in composition instance!
console.log('all done!')
```

Unless you're writing production code and actions are being batched, the above update to redux should be synchronous.

Furthermore, it should be noted that `this.setState()`, for updating local state to the component, can be asynchronous, which may be what you're thinking about when you say that updates to state are async.